# Add icon to "About Eclipse Platform" dialog in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

If you bring up the Help -> "About Eclipse Platform" dialog in Eclipse, it displays a dialog showing the Eclipse version as well as a bunch of icons at the bottom for major features such as Eclipse itself, m2e, GWT, etc. Clicking one of those icons brings up a dialog showing the components of that feature with version information.

How do I add my own icon to that row that behaves the same way as the existing icons?

Comment: See http://ekkescorner.wordpress.com/2010/06/13/brand-your-feature-and-be-part-of-about-eclipse/

Comment: That works: if you make it an answer I will accept it. I would also like to point out that it does not work when debugging a plugin: it has to be installed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See http://ekkescorner.wordpress.com/2010/06/13/brand-your-feature-and-be-part-of-about-eclipse/ essentially the magic to know is that this is called a 'branding plug-in'.